# Emulating srcset in CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive-images, srcset

I know that `imageset` is the CSS equivalent to HTML's `srcset` attribute. However the [current spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#funcdef-image-set) only supports the `x` pixel density units, not the `w` and `h` sizing units.

For example:

```
<img srcset="high.jpg 2000w, medium.jpg 1200w, low.jpg 800w">
```

If I resize my browser window to 400px wide Chrome first loads `low.jpg`. As I make the window wider it loads first `medium.jpg` then `high.jpg`. The point at which is switches is dependent on my display's pixel density so my retina Macbook loads the higher resolution images at half window size compared to my old Windows laptop.

How can I reproduce this behaviour for a CSS background image? I started doing it by specifying a bunch of `min-width` and `max-resolution` media queries but it quickly became a tangled mess. There must be a better way. I'm willing to use a JS polyfill if available.

Comment: I'm assuming you have looked at [Picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)?

Comment: Picturefill is a polyfill for `srcset` and `<picture>` in HTML, it does nothing for CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no easy way (yet?) to match `srcset-w` features in CSS.

You should read this great article on the topic: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/

Answer (score 0):

CSS media query: [pixel ratio](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

Or [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)

Comment: Picturefill is a polyfill for `srcset` and `<picture>` in HTML, it does nothing for CSS.